# Validating HttpRequestMessage body

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, controller

I have a web api and I wanted to validate the request coming in.

Currently I have this in my web api controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSomething([FromBody]SomeObject request)
{
    var test= request.Number;
    //omit
}

public class SomeObject
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public double Number {get;set;}
}
```

Currently if I send in a request and set Number equal to a string or a non double, when the request comes to the server the Number is just set to zero. How should I validate the request when it comes in because I don' want it to be zero when it comes in?

Comment: In that case you would send the client a 400 Bad Request http status response. You can't validate it unless you receive the request so you can't prevent the client trying to send garbage.

Comment: @Crowcoder on the server side, the garbage is just set as zero for the number property however that turns it into a valid request. I cant check against the number zero

Comment: If `Number` is a nullable int (?) do you get null instead?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes that works, thank you for the idea

Comment: @DeVonte you don't need to change the type of the property to get it work. Just look at my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an error and return to the user you can do check `ModelState` property of your controller API.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]SomeObject value)
{
    if(this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // If you enter here all data are set correctly
        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        // here you use BadRequest method and pass the ModelState property.
        return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
    }
}
```

There is nothing to do, change in your `Number` property. The only modification I do is to change the return type of your action by using `IHttpActionResult`.

When the data set for `Number` if incorrect you will something like that on the client site:

```
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "value.number": [
            "Error converting value \"dfsdf\" to type 'System.Double'. Path 'number', line 2, position 19."
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be reused in all controllers by annotating it method with this filter.

```
[Valid] //here  we apply the filter and request made to this model is validated by validation rules on the model
[HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage someMethod(SomeValidationModel someValidationModel)
 {
    //some logic
 }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace mynamespace.filters
{
    public class ValidAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {

            if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```